# 404 error with spring mvc + tiles but no console error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles

I am new to spring and have been following the tutorials on http://viralpatel.net and currently have an issue with the [Spring 3 MVC: Tiles Plugin Tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse/)

I Have searched both google and stackoverflow for a solution to this and could not find one so appoligies if this is a duplicate.

I'm basically getting the following 404 error in my browser when I try to run the code from the above tutorial

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Spring3MVC/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp
```

but I get no console errors:

```
    01-Nov-2012 13:37:32 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C
:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0.33\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Windo
ws\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common F
iles\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Progra
m Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2010\Office14;C:\
Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0.33\bin;C:\Program Files\maven-2.2.1\bin
;.
01-Nov-2012 13:37:32 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring3MVC' did not find a m
atching property.
01-Nov-2012 13:37:32 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
01-Nov-2012 13:37:32 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 533 ms
01-Nov-2012 13:37:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
01-Nov-2012 13:37:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
01-Nov-2012 13:37:33 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
01-Nov-2012 13:37:33 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
01-Nov-2012 13:37:33 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
01-Nov-2012 13:37:33 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/27  config=null
01-Nov-2012 13:37:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1637 ms
```

this is my web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
        <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

this is my spring-servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

this is my tiles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition"
        template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="contact" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Manager" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contact.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

The rest of the code is an exact copy of the tutorial above, which builds on [handling forms tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/) which I appear to have working perfectly. below is a screen grab of the project in eclipse including jars in case someone thinks it may be an issue with a missing or wrong jar

[image: eclipse project]

Any help/advice/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the problem

In your tiles.xml the layout.jsp URL is

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp
```

And your jsp folder is

```
WebContent/jsp/
```

Comment: thank You, I had been staring at it for last few hours , can't believe it was something so silly. much appreciated